# Open Source IDE for C/C++ on Ubuntu with native dark theme

Tags: python, software-development, c++, ubuntu, ide

I am using Pycharm community edition for my Python development, looking for something like this for C/C++. The basic requirements are

- native support for dark theme like Dracula etc.
- free and open source
- to be used on Ubuntu (20.04 or 22.04)
- all the usual stuffs like showing documentation on mouse hover, static analysis, autocomplete, insert code snippet, linting and autoformatting according to some standard, suggestions on variable names and possible refactoring etc.
- Relatively easier to set up and run, like Pycharm etc. Not something super-geeky like Vim or Emacs. I want to get up to speed with development, rather than fighting the IDE.

Here is why some of the common recommendations did not suit me.

Code::block, seems to have a horrible dark theme in the sense, it is not native, but somehow imposed by my OS, and hides a lot of menu items, using dark grey text on black window borders making them nearly invisible.

Was using atom from github for sometime, but Microsoft is sunsetting the project.

Somehow I just do not like Visual Studio code (actually, want to avoid anything from microsoft, given what they did to Atom), but may be have to resort to it eventually.

Tried netbeans, but the menu items and windows seem a bit too snappy and not smooth, if you know what I mean. It gives the feeling of an application from 199x on windows 95 on a machine with 64 MB ram, that could not support today's GUI applications. The documentation support, autocompletion, showing method arguments dynamically etc. are just not up to the mark.

May be I am a bit too picky, but wondering if there is any choice at all, something like Pycharm for C++.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this personally, however I've seen some projects built using the GNOME Builder IDE. It should work great if you want to create something specific for GNOME/Gtk, however it should work for "generic" C/C++ projects as well. From what I gather, any project using CMake/Make or Meson for a build system should work OK. I cannot guarantee anything regarding feature parity, however it is being actively worked on [GNOME Gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-builder).

- Builder Homepage: [GNOME Builder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder)
- Flatpak: `flatpak install [--user] org.gnome.Builder` Use the --user switch for installing as the current user, & not system wide (which is the default).

If non-foss IDEs are not a dealbreaker, I would recommend considering CLion. The advantage is that the UI/UX will be exactly the same as the current Python IDE you're using, however, it's also not "native" to the GNOME desktop environment. In general, Jetbrains tools do not respect light/dark theme settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is another project Eclipse Theia that is similar to Visual Studio Code. It is able to use extensions from Visual Studio Code, and I think it supports C++ and Python.

https://theia-ide.org/